# How do I parse some of the data from a large xml file?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I need to extract the location and radius data from a large xml file that is formatted as below and store the data in 2-dimensional ndarray.  This is my first time using Python and I can't find anything about the best way to do this.

```
<species name="MyHeterotrophEPS" header="family,genealogy,generation,birthday,biomass,inert,capsule,growthRate,volumeRate,locationX,locationY,locationZ,radius,totalRadius">
0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,77.0645361927206,-0.1001871531330136,-0.0013358287084401814,4.523853439106942,234.14575280979898,123.92820420047076,0.0,0.6259920275663835;
0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,108.5705297969604,-0.1411462759900182,-0.001881950346533576,1.0429122163754276,144.1066875513379,72.24884428367467,0.0,0.7017581019907897;
.
.
.
</species>
```

Edit:I mean "large" by human standards.  I am not having any memory issues with it.

Comment: The XML text data is essentially a CSV file...

Comment: Is this "large" because there are lots of other nodes you don't care about, because there are lots of `species` nodes, or because the contents of the `species` node are large? (And, is "large" an actual problem—as in trying to read it all at once gives you a `MemoryError` or throws your computer into swap hell or something?)

Comment: The contents of species tag is what is "large."  No, this is not an actual problem I just thought it might be relevant.

Comment: Your `locationX` values have angle brackets in them (e.g., `4.5238534391069>42`). How are those supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: OK, if you just have one giant `species` tag in each document, and "large" isn't enough to cause a problem, you can use Martijn Pieters' answer.

Comment: Those angle brackets were typos on my part. I have now edited them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You essentially have CSV data in the XML text value.

Use [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the XML, then use [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to load that text into an array:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('yourxmlfilename.xml')
species = tree.find(".//species[@name='MyHeterotrophEPS']")
names = species.attrib['header']
array = numpy.genfromtxt((line.rstrip(';') for line in species.text.splitlines()), 
    delimiter=',', names=names)
```

Note the generator expression, with a [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) call; this turns the text of the XML element into a sequence of lines, which `.genfromtxt()` is quite happy to receive. We do remove the trailing `;` character from each line.

For your sample input (minus the `.` lines), this results in:

```
array([ (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 77.0645361927206, -0.1001871531330136, -0.0013358287084401814, 4.523853439106942, 234.14575280979898, 123.92820420047076, 0.0, 0.6259920275663835),
       (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108.5705297969604, -0.1411462759900182, -0.001881950346533576, 1.0429122163754276, 144.1066875513379, 72.24884428367467, 0.0, 0.7017581019907897)], 
      dtype=[('family', '<f8'), ('genealogy', '<f8'), ('generation', '<f8'), ('birthday', '<f8'), ('biomass', '<f8'), ('inert', '<f8'), ('capsule', '<f8'), ('growthRate', '<f8'), ('volumeRate', '<f8'), ('locationX', '<f8'), ('locationY', '<f8'), ('locationZ', '<f8'), ('radius', '<f8'), ('totalRadius', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Beat me to it, and I missed the part about importing into `numpy` (which means you can skip the `csv.reader`)…

Comment: Isn't it spelled `genfromtxt`, not `genfromtext`?

Comment: Also, I just noticed the semicolons at the end of each line, which need to be fixed or the last column will end up all `nan`.

Comment: The `nan`s remaining in the output are because of the angle brackets in the `locationX`, which I asked the OP about in a comment. From the latest edit, it looks like those were just a typo; with the edited sample data, everything works perfectly.

Comment: @abarnert: Fixed in the OP post now, answer updated to reflect the change.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That should be perfect.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If your XML is just that `species` node, it's pretty simple, and Martijn Pieters has already explained it better than I can.

But if you've got a ton of `species` nodes in the document, and it's too large to fit the whole thing into memory, you can use [`iterparse`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) instead of `parse`:

```
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event, node in ET.iterparse('species.xml'):
    if node.tag == 'species':
        name = node.attr['name']
        names = node.attr['header']
        csvdata = (line.rstrip(';') for line in node.text.splitlines())
        array = np.genfromtxt(csvdata, delimiter=',', names=names)
        # do something with the array.
```

This won't help if you just have one super-gigantic `species` node, because even `iterparse` (or similar solutions like a SAX parser) parse one entire node at a time. You'd need to find an XML library that lets you stream the *text* of large nodes, and off the top of my head, I don't think of any stdlib or popular third-party parsers that can do that.

Comment: `names` takes a comma-separated string too; I didn't bother with the `.split(',')` because of that.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is *really large*, use [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [`SAX`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html).

If the file is not that large (i.e. fits into memory), [`minidom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) might be easier to work with.

Each line seems to be a simple string of comma-separated numbers, so you can sipmly do `line.split(',')`.

Comment: Using etree or sax won't help if this is (as it appears to be) a simple document with one giant tag full of CSV data. But the OP hasn't given us enough information to do more than guess whether that's the case…

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a one-tag file or there are many tags with this kind of data…